# C# IQueryable definition for different entity types

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, generics, iqueryable

```
//I need to deifne productQuery here
    if (test == true)
    {
      var productQuery = ordersRepository.ProductIn; //it returns IQueryable<ProductIn> type
    }
    else
    {
      var productQuery = ordersRepository.ProductOut; //it returns IQueryable<ProductOut> type
    }
```

How can I define the productQuery variable?

Thank you!

[EDIT]

```
dynamic productType;

if (test == true)
    {
      productType = ordersRepository.ProductIn; //it returns IQueryable<ProductIn> type
    }
    else
    {
      productType = ordersRepository.ProductOut; //it returns IQueryable<ProductOut> type
    }

var productQuery = productType as IQueryable<ProductIn>;
if (productQuery == null)
{
     productQuery = productType as IQueryable<ProductIn>;
}
```

I do this way, is it right way?

Comment: Into second example: try `object` instead of `dynamic`.

Comment: I tried with object but, error message say 'Error 16 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
'

Comment: you must call Linq-methods after `cast`.. `var foo = productQuery as IQueryable<ProductIn>;
if (foo != null) { foo.Where(..)` I have not tested it, but I believe that works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could declare it as a *dynamic* type, if you're ok with deferring type resolution until runtime.

```
dynamic productQuery;
if (test == true)
{
    productQuery = ordersRepository.ProductIn; //it returns IQueryable<ProductIn> type
}
else
{
    productQuery = ordersRepository.ProductOut; //it returns IQueryable<ProductOut> type
}
```

Your other choice is to declare it as an *object* type, and then cast it back to the other type as needed.

```
object productQuery;

if (test == true)
{
    productQuery = ordersRepository.ProductIn; //it returns IQueryable<ProductIn> type
}
else
{
    productQuery = ordersRepository.ProductOut; //it returns IQueryable<ProductOut> type
}

// ... more logic ...
var unboxed = productQuery as IQueryable<ProductIn>;
if (unboxed != null) {
    unboxed.Where( ... and away you go with Linq ...);
}
```

**Update after op's edit**

Let's say you have a dynamic type *productQuery*.  To use Linq on it, you need to define the types of the delegate.  Let's say that types *ProductIn* and *ProductOut* each have a string-type property *ProductNo*.  Then you could write your query like this, again making use of *dynamic*.

```
productQuery.Where(new Func<dynamic,bool>(item => item.productNo));
```

**However ...** I think you could make your life a lot easier by changing your whole approach.  You're clearly working against a common interface for *ProductIn* and *ProductOut*, so why not define that explicitly?

```
public interface IProduct
{
    public string ProductNo { get; set; }
}

public class ProductIn : IProduct { ... }
public class ProductOut : IProduct { ... }
```

Now your code becomes a lot simpler.  Write it like this:

```
IQueryable<IProduct> productQuery;

if (test == true)
{
    productQuery = ordersRepository.ProductIn; //it returns IQueryable<ProductIn> type
}
else
{
    productQuery = ordersRepository.ProductOut; //it returns IQueryable<ProductOut> type
}

string myResult = productQuery.Where(item => item.productNo == productNo).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: or.. `if((productQuery as IQueryable<ProductIn>) != null) .. else if((productQuery as IQueryable<ProductOut>) != null)`

Comment: Ty for your comment! I tried this, if (productQuery.GetType() == typeof(IQueryable<ProductIn>))
            {
                productQuery = productQuery as IQueryable<ProductIn>;
            }
            else
            {
                productQuery = productQuery as IQueryable<ProductOut>;
            }

            productQuery = productQuery.Where(x => x.productNo == productNo); BUT Error message say "Error 15 Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type"

Comment: @Expertwannabe can you write a separate Linq query for each type inside the conditional blocks?

Comment: @dbaseman I write only one Linq query 'productQuery = productQuery.Where(x => x.productNo == productNo);' because both object has productNo.

Comment: @Expertwannabe I think a better approach would be to define the interface for the two classes, and work against that.  See my updated answer.